# How to obtain a copy of my own article from an APS (American Physical Society) journal?

Tags: publications, copyright, publishers, online-publication

I recently published an article in one of the journals of the American Physical Society (APS). Our university library does not have a subscription to this particular journal, so I don't have access to the published version of the article.

On the other hand, APS allows to share the published version of the paper with colleagues and even to put it on the university website (see [FAQ at APS](https://journals.aps.org/copyrightFAQ.html), also [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/am-i-allowed-to-share-a-final-copy-of-my-published-paper-privately/56520#56520)).

In the past, other journals have provided me with an (electronic) copy of my article after publication, which I'm not allowed to share. However, it seems that APS won't give me automatic access to my paper. At least I haven't found any option on the authors page and no email was sent to me.

Is there a way to obtain a (electronic) copy of my article from APS?

I know that I could buy the article, either through the library service or our own group budget. But it feels kind of strange to buy one's own paper back from the publisher.
I could also ask someone from another university who does have access to it to send me a copy.

But is there an official way to obtain the paper?

Comment: Have you tried contacting APS?

Comment: @ dimpol I haven't contacted APS yet, since I was first curious what my options are.

Comment: Don’t they send you the article anyway or allow you to download it via their submission system?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Well, no. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question. Have made an edit, to make that clearer.

Comment: Not that I know of, though I'm sure that the editor would send it to you if you asked. In this case, I'd feel pretty dang justified in using #icanhazpdf or scihub.

Comment: @AJK in the present, scihub does not work anymore for APS journals, and the journal does not offer published version of the paper to the author. Perhaps the best option would be to ask a friend with a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the journal editor directly to send a copy of your publication. I will help to clearly summarise your situation. This will be something they encounter on a regular basis and if the editor replies with a strict "no", you can still ask a colleague for the download. It is your work, so the editor will likely be understanding. Hope this helps!